# Use group by find top n，can it reduce the disk I/0?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I want to find top n in a set of data in sqlite db in android. I have two choices to get the result. One is select all data from db, and order in java,
another one is use `group by` and `order by` in sql.

my question is:
Using `group by`, can it reduce the disk I/O really?

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` could be optimized with an (explicit or implicit) index.